# Inequality $a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + k(a^3b + b^3c + c^3a)$ $\ge (k + 1)(ab^3 + bc^3 + ca^3)$ where $k\in [0,1]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, rearrangement-inequality

> Prove the following inequality for all real numbers $a, b, c$ and for $k \in [0, 1]$:
> $$a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + k(a^3b + b^3c + c^3a) \geq (k + 1)(ab^3 + bc^3 + ca^3)$$

I have tried to prove by Rearrangement inequality (supose $a \geq b \geq c$):
$$aa^3 + bb^3 + cc^3 \geq ab^3 + bc^3 + ca^3$$

So, by simplifying $k$ we have got the following inequality:
$$a^3b + b^3c + c^3a \geq ab^3 + bc^3 + ca^3$$

Which seems true by some rearrangement-type inequality, but I am not able to figure out and point it clearly. And also, what is $k \in [0, 1]$ for?

Comment: Hint: As a function of $k$ the difference between the two sides is an affine function . So it is enough to prove the inequality for $k=0$ and for $k=1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you please explain what is an affine function of $k$?

Comment: It is a function of the form $Ak+B$ where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation!

Comment: $a^3b + b^3c + c^3a \geq ab^3 + bc^3 + ca^3$ cannot always be true since the direction of the inequality will reverse if we replace $a,b,c$ by $b,a,c$. For a specific example, let $a=1, b=2, c=3$. LHS$=53$. RHS$=65$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given inequality is equivalent to
$$ a^4 + b^4 + c^4 - (ab^3 + bc^3 + ca^3) \geq k\left((ab^3 + bc^3 + ca^3)-(a^3b + b^3c + c^3a)\right)$$

For any fixed $a,b,c$, the right hand side as a linear function of $k$ attains its maximum when $k=0$ or $k=1$. Hence it is enough to prove the case when $k=0$ and the case when $k=1$.

##### The case $k=0$

We want to prove $a^4 + b^4 + c^4 \ge ab^3 + bc^3 + ca^3$.

By AM-GM, we have $$
\frac{3a^4+b^4}4=\frac{a^4+a^4+a^4+b^4}4\ge\sqrt[4]{a^4a^4a^4b^4}=ab^3$$
So $$a^4 + b^4 + c^4 =\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{3a^4+b^4}4\ge\sum_{\text{cyc}}ab^3=ab^3 + bc^3 + ca^3$$

The equality holds iff $a=b=c$.

##### The case $k=1$

We want to prove $$a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + a^3b + b^3c + c^3a \ge 2(ab^3 + bc^3 + ca^3)$$
which turns out to be a very strong inequality that is hard to prove.

The following one-line proof was given by darij grinberg originally [here at AoPS Online](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h6026p252585)

$$\begin{aligned}
&\qquad\left(a^4+b^4+c^4\right)+\left(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a\right)-2\left(b^3a+c^3b+a^3c\right)\\
&=\frac12\left((a^2-b^2+ab-ca)^2+(b^2-c^2+bc-ab)^2+(c^2-a^2+ca-bc)^2\right)
\end{aligned}$$

Another one-line proof was given by Sergey Markelov originally at the same thread [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h6026p1167938).

$$\begin{aligned}
&\qquad\left(a^4+b^4+c^4\right)+\left(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a\right)-2\left(b^3a+c^3b+a^3c\right)\\ 
&=
\frac14\left(a^2-ab-ac+b^2+2bc-2c^2\right)^2 +\frac34\left(a^2+ab-ac-b^2\right)^2\\
\end{aligned}$$

The equality holds iff $a=b=c$ or $(\frac1a: \frac1b: \frac1c)$ is one of the three cyclic permutations of $(\sin\frac{\pi}9:\sin\frac{-4\pi}9:\sin\frac{2\pi}9)$.

Here are some data when the equality happens nontrivially.
$\quad a = 1/\sin\frac{\pi}9=2.9238\cdots$
$\quad b = 1/\sin\frac{-4\pi}9=-1.0154\cdots$
$\quad c = 1/\sin\frac{2\pi}9=1.5557\cdots$
$\quad \sum_{\text{cyc}}a^4= 80.$
$\quad \sum_{\text{cyc}}a^3b= -16.$
$\quad \sum_{\text{cyc}}ab^3 = 32.$

##### A remark on the range of $k$

The given inequality is valid for all $k\in[-2,1]$.

For any other $k$, the inequality fails for some $a,b,c$.